# Custom Extension for Email Reminder

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, custom, email-reminders

I have developed Magento website version 1.9.2.4. Now i want to create custom extension for email reminder which provide configure two field.

1. Hours before email is sent
2. Email address(es) to send email to (separated by commas)

The purpose of email reminder is any order that hasn't been processed in last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields to the admin by using a system.xml in your modules /etc directory

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <moduleconf translate="label" module="namespace_module">
            <label>Module Settings</label>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </moduleconf>
    </tabs>

    <sections>
        <namespace_module translate="label" module="namespace_module">
            <label>Your module Settings</label>
            <tab>moduleconf</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <namespace_module translate="label" module="namespace_module">
                    <label>Your Module Settings</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <field_name translate="label">
                            <label>Your Field Label</label>
                            <comment><![CDATA[A field comment]]></comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </field_name>
                    </fields>
                </namespace_module>
            </groups>
        </namespace_module>
    </sections>
</config>
```

You can then retrieve these values with:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('namespace_module/config_section/field_name');
```